# How to get a count after all the iterations are completed?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, count, iteration

I have a count variable which will count the number of when a certain condition are met.
I am using JavaScript. Below is the example of my codes.

```
let count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data.value == 1) {
       count++;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

I noticed that the value of count will always return 0.
How can I get the final value of count after all the iterations are completed?

Comment: What is `data`, an array? If so `Array`'s dont have a `value` property, did you mean to access the array element's property, eg `data[i].value`?

Comment: I think you need to add the example value of your data variable

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes it should be data[i].value. Thanks for asking. I just noticed my mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `data`'s value is an array of object like below,

you might need to add the index of array on the value checking,

`if(data[i].value == 1)`

please check the full example code below

```js
let count = 0;
const data = [
  { name: 'a', value: 1 },
  { name: 'b', value: 1 },
  { name: 'n', value: 1 },
  { name: 'm', value: 1 },
  { name: 'x', value: 1 },
]
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].value == 1) {
       count++;
    }
}
console.log("count's final value is ", count);
```

Answer (score 1):

please try adding the keyword "var" before the variable count

```
var count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data.value == 1) {
       count++;
    }
}
alert(count);
```

On the other hand, please make sure there is a case where data.value is "1", otherwise of course the count will be 0

Comment: It should be data[i].value instead. Thanks for your respond. Really appreciate it!